# Can't get the count value through while loop in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, count, while-loop

I need to get the users who sends the message count as well.

```
$userlist = mysql_query("select count(distinct m.subject) as msgcnt, u.name from message as m, message_users as mu, users as u where m.owner_id = u.id and m.id=mu.msg_id and mu.user_id='$u_id'group by name") or mysql_error();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($userlist))
        {               
            echo $row['name']."<br />";
        }
```

How to get the count values by using while loop..

Comment: $userlist = mysql_query("select count(distinct m.subject) as msgcnt, u.name from message as m, message_users as mu, users as u where m.owner_id = u.id and m.id=mu.msg_id and mu.user_id='$u_id'group by name") or mysql_error();

query issue might be give space mu.user_id='$_id' group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already are storing the said count in an alias `msgcnt`, simply echo it.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($userlist))
        {               
            echo $row['name']." : ".$row['msgcnt']."<br />";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $row['msgcnt'].'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get a associated array!

```
$userlist = mysql_query("select count(distinct m.subject) as msgcnt, u.name from message as m, message_users as mu, users as u where m.owner_id = u.id and m.id=mu.msg_id and mu.user_id='$u_id'group by name") or mysql_error();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($userlist)) {               
        echo $row['name']."<br />";           
        echo $row['msgcnt']."<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `msgcnt` when you specified alias as `msgcnt`

```
echo $row['msgcnt']."<br />";
```